# MVC View not displaying validation errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, entity-framework-4

i've got some validations in my mvc project. However, when i sumbit an empty form or form where some required fields have not been entered, it does not stay within the same form/view and show the errors. I cant see any modal errors (i.e amount is required field)

for example, here are some attributes in my modal

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1, MinimumLength = 1)]
    public string Period { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime ModifyDate { get; set; }
```

Here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
         public ActionResult StopScheduled([Bind(Prefix = "item")]  BillPayModel model)
         {
             //getUsers();

             try
             {
                 if (ModelState.IsValid)
                 {

                    //save stuff into db
                     db.SaveChanges();

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
                 }
             }


             catch (FormatException)
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
             }


             return RedirectToAction("StopScheduled");
         }

    }
```

here is my view

```
@if (Model !=null)
{
    if (Model.IsSuccess == true)
    {
        <span><center><font color = "green">Successfully Completed Transaction!  </font></center></span>
    }
    else
    {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "ERROR! Please make sure you have entered correct details"); 
    }
}

@if (Model ==null)
{ 
    using (Html.BeginForm("BillPay", "BillPay", FormMethod.Post, new {}))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true);

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.AccountNumber)</div>
         @Html.DropDownList("Accounts",  "-- Select User --")  

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PayeeID)</div>
        @Html.DropDownList("PayeeID",  "-- Select User --")         


        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Amount)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Amount,new {style = "width:150px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Amount)
        </div>        

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleDate) (i.e 20/10/2013 10:00)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ScheduleDate,new {style = "width:250px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleDate)
        </div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Period)</div>
        <div>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Period,new {style = "width:150px"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Period)
        </div> 

        <input type="submit" value ="Submit" style="width:8%;height:5%"/> 
        <input type="reset" value ="reset" style="width:8%;height:5%"/>   
    }
}
else
{

}
```

Comment: Did you include `jquery.validation.js` in you (master)page?

Comment: This is what I thinking :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are making a new request with RedirectToAction so the validation of your model set to valid. To solve your problem you need to do like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StopScheduled([Bind(Prefix = "item")]  BillPayModel model)
{
         try
         {
             if (ModelState.IsValid)
             {
                //save stuff into db
                 db.SaveChanges();
             }
             else
             {
                 ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
             }
         }
         catch (FormatException)
         {
             ModelState.AddModelError("", "Could not Stop Scheduled Payment");
         }
         return View(model);
}
```

And in the view you should change the Html.ValidationSummary excludePropertyErrors to false, like this:

```
if (Model.IsSuccess == true)
{
    <span><center><font color = "green">Successfully Completed Transaction!  </font></center></span>
}
else
{
     @Html.ValidationSummary(false, "ERROR! Please make sure you have entered correct details"); 
}
```

To show them oneach input you need yoo change your if statement (Model==null).

Comment: this didnt really resolve it. all i still get is "ERROR! Please make sure you have entered correct details". WHy is my from not been displayed when i submit with that error?

Comment: @kayze Yes ofc it only shows that because you dont show your validation message if model is not null.